# What is the applescript code to open a folder

Tags: applescript

Right now I am using this code:

```
    open folder
```

and it seems like it can not find the folder.
Do I have to specify a folder?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically `open` does not open folders.

You have to open a folder via the Finder and specify an HFS string path, `alias` or Finder folder specifier:

```
tell application "Finder" to open (path to desktop)
```

or

```
tell application "Finder" to open home
```

or

```
tell application "Finder" to open folder "Applications" of startup disk
```

Comment: how do you open a folder in documents?

Comment: `tell application "Finder" to open folder "myFolder" of (path to documents folder)`